# Uso de TRIGGER en SQL - ¿Cómo Sumar de forma Condicional usando Disparadores?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes conexiones en mi BBDD
[image: Relaciones BBDD]

Lo que quiero es crear un TRIGGER que me actualice los datos de **TablaPosiciones** cuando haya un cambio en **Resultado**

Yo estaba intentado realizarlo de la siguiente forma, pero solo pude lograr que me actualizara **Pj** (Partidos Jugados), **Gf** (Goles a Favor), **Gc** (Goles en Contra) con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TablaP ON Resultado FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @Id INT = (SELECT EquipoId FROM inserted),
    @Gf INT = (SELECT EquipoId FROM inserted),
    @Gc INT = (SELECT EquipoId FROM inserted)
UPDATE TablaPosiciones SET 
    Gf = (SELECT SUM(Gf) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id), 
    Gc = (SELECT SUM(Gc) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id),
    Pj = (SELECT COUNT(EquipoId) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id),
    Pg = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @Gf > @Gc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id),
    Pp = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @Gf < @Gc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id),
    Pe = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @Gf = @Gc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Resultado WHERE EquipoId = @Id)

WHERE EquipoId = @Id END
```

Aún no logro que me actualice **Pg** (Partidos Ganados), **Pp** (Partidos Perdidos), **Pe** (Paritdos Empatados).

Alguna solución?

Comment: Te recomiendo que TablaPosiciones sea una vista y no una tabla. Así no necesitas un trigger cada vez que cambie el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tu problema viene desde el diseño de las tablas. Tienes correcto el hecho de tener una tabla de equipos, pero no puedes tener una tabla de resultados que solo sean de un equipo porque tendrías que estar insertando 2 filas por cada partido y eso termina siendo una duplicación muy importante de datos. Tampoco es necesaria una tabla de posiciones porque eso varía mucho y es mejor calcularlo al vuelo.

Para una tabla de resultado de partidos, recomiendo esta opción.

```
CREATE TABLE Partidos(
    ID              int,
    Fecha           date,
    EquipoLocal     int,
    EquipoVisitante int,
    GolesLocal      int,
    GolesVisitante  int,
    GanaLocal       AS IIF( GolesLocal > GolesVisitante, 1, 0),
    GanaVisitante   AS IIF( GolesLocal < GolesVisitante, 1, 0),
    Empate          AS IIF( GolesLocal = GolesVisitante, 1, 0)
);
```

Ahí tenemos 3 columnas calculadas que no ocupan espacio en la base de datos pero nos ayuda a reducir el código que hay que escribir.

Para la tabla de posiciones, tendríamos que hacer que la tabla de partidos muestre 2 filas, por cada una. Pareciera que es contraproducente el diseño, pero las consultas son bastante eficientes. Esto lo logramos usando la operación `APPLY` que funciona similar al `JOIN` pero podemos usar columnas de tablas definidas previamente en la consulta.

```
SELECT  e.Nombre AS Equipo,
        e.Grupo,
        PJ     = COUNT(*),
        PG     = SUM( PG),
        PE     = SUM( PE),
        PP     = SUM( PP),
        GF     = SUM( GF),
        GC     = SUM( GC),
        DG     = SUM( GF) - SUM( GC),
        Puntos = SUM( (PG * 3) + PE)
FROM Partidos p 
CROSS APPLY(VALUES( EquipoLocal, GolesLocal, GolesVisitante, GanaLocal, GanaVisitante, Empate),
                    ( EquipoVisitante, GolesVisitante, GolesLocal, GanaVisitante, GanaLocal, Empate)) R(Equipo, GF, GC, PG, PP, PE)
JOIN Equipos e ON R.Equipo = e.Id
GROUP BY E.Grupo, e.Nombre
```

Si no te sientes cómodo usando la sentencia `VALUES` puedes usar `UNION ALL`. Si te fijas, no usamos el `FROM` porque las columnas pertenecen a la tabla `Partidos` que indicamos anteriormente.

```
CROSS APPLY(SELECT EquipoLocal, GolesLocal, GolesVisitante, GanaLocal, GanaVisitante, Empate 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT EquipoVisitante, GolesVisitante, GolesLocal, GanaVisitante, GanaLocal, Empate) R(Equipo, GF, GC, PG, PP, PE)
```

Desgraciadamente, no podemos asignar números de fila según los resultados de las funciones de agregado, por lo tanto, tenemos que ponerlo en una subconsulta o CTE en este caso. De una vez lo convertimos en una vista.

```
CREATE VIEW Posiciones
AS
    WITH ctePosiciones AS(
        SELECT  e.Nombre AS Equipo,
                e.Grupo,
                PJ     = COUNT(*),
                PG     = SUM( PG),
                PE     = SUM( PE),
                PP     = SUM( PP),
                GF     = SUM( GF),
                GC     = SUM( GC),
                DG     = SUM( GF) - SUM( GC),
                Puntos = SUM( (PG * 3) + PE)
        FROM Partidos p 
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES( EquipoLocal, GolesLocal, GolesVisitante, GanaLocal, GanaVisitante, Empate),
                          ( EquipoVisitante, GolesVisitante, GolesLocal, GanaVisitante, GanaLocal, Empate)) R(Equipo, GF, GC, PG, PP, PE)
        JOIN Equipos e ON R.Equipo = e.Id
        GROUP BY E.Grupo, e.Nombre
    )
    SELECT Posicion = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Puntos DESC, DG DESC, GF ASC),
        PosicionGrupo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grupo ORDER BY Puntos DESC, DG DESC, GF ASC),
        PJ,     
        PG,     
        PE,     
        PP,     
        GF,     
        GC,     
        DG,     
        Puntos 
    FROM ctePosiciones;
```

Para finalizar, dejo un ejemplo completo con datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE Equipos(
    Id  int,
    Nombre  varchar(100),
    Participaciones int,
    Grupo int);
INSERT INTO Equipos
VALUES( 1, 'Real Martin', 10, 1),
      ( 2, 'Varselona', 10, 1),
      ( 3, 'Munchester Yunaited', 10, 2),
      ( 4, 'Yubentus', 10, 2),
      ( 5, 'Bayer Miunik', 10, 2),
      ( 6, 'PCG', 10, 3),
      ( 7, 'Tinder de Milano', 10, 3);

CREATE TABLE Partidos(
    ID              int,
    Fecha           date,
    EquipoLocal     int,
    EquipoVisitante int,
    GolesLocal      int,
    GolesVisitante  int,
    GanaLocal       AS IIF( GolesLocal > GolesVisitante, 1, 0),
    GanaVisitante   AS IIF( GolesLocal < GolesVisitante, 1, 0),
    Empate          AS IIF( GolesLocal = GolesVisitante, 1, 0)
);
INSERT INTO Partidos
VALUES( 1, '20220101', 1, 2, 3, 2),
      ( 2, '20220201', 3, 4, 2, 2),
      ( 3, '20220301', 5, 6, 1, 2),
      ( 4, '20220401', 7, 1, 3, 0),
      ( 5, '20220501', 2, 3, 5, 3),
      ( 6, '20220601', 4, 5, 2, 1),
      ( 7, '20220701', 6, 7, 0, 0),
      ( 8, '20220801', 5, 3, 1, 2);
GO
CREATE VIEW Posiciones
AS
    WITH ctePosiciones AS(
        SELECT  e.Nombre AS Equipo,
                e.Grupo,
                PJ     = COUNT(*),
                PG     = SUM( PG),
                PE     = SUM( PE),
                PP     = SUM( PP),
                GF     = SUM( GF),
                GC     = SUM( GC),
                DG     = SUM( GF) - SUM( GC),
                Puntos = SUM( (PG * 3) + PE)
        FROM Partidos p 
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES( EquipoLocal, GolesLocal, GolesVisitante, GanaLocal, GanaVisitante, Empate),
                          ( EquipoVisitante, GolesVisitante, GolesLocal, GanaVisitante, GanaLocal, Empate)) R(Equipo, GF, GC, PG, PP, PE)
        JOIN Equipos e ON R.Equipo = e.Id
        GROUP BY E.Grupo, e.Nombre
    )
    SELECT Posicion = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Puntos DESC, DG DESC, GF ASC),
        PosicionGrupo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grupo ORDER BY Puntos DESC, DG DESC, GF ASC),
        PJ,     
        PG,     
        PE,     
        PP,     
        GF,     
        GC,     
        DG,     
        Puntos 
    FROM ctePosiciones;

GO

SELECT *
FROM Posiciones
ORDER BY Posicion;
```